# Can I monetize my YouTube channel on a F1 Visa in the US and get paid in India?

Tags: usa, student-visa, non-residents

I have a YouTube channel and hired a content creator, who is in India, for all of my videos. I won't be earning money in a US bank account. My AdSense account will have details of my Indian bank. Isn't it similar to being in India and maintaining the channel since there are no transaction to a US bank account?

Comment: Related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12711/can-a-student-upload-youtube-videos-from-their-home-country-while-on-f1-visa/12716#12716

Comment: I don't think that answers my question. I want to know how different it is to have to manage it from India than from the US.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't answer your question. That's why I used the word "related," didn't say it was a "Duplicate," and didn't vote to close.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. This is in fact my first question here.

Comment: Same question. So did you find the answer for it?

Comment: It makes much more sense that the INS would read the F1's prohibition on "work" to mean _work outside the F1 holder's academic program_, not  _work paid for in another country_.